# Export HIVE to a CSV

Tags: csv, hive, libreoffice

I have some data in HIVE, and I would like to see it in LibreOffice.

How do I export this data and later import it on Libreoffice

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! What did you try so far and what diffuclties do you expereince with your current approach?

Comment: I created the perl script:

   use Text::CSV;

   my $csv = Text::CSV->new( ) or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
   $csv->eol ("\r\n");

   while (my $line = readline) {
      chomp $line;
      my @cols = split /\x01/, $line;
      $csv->print(*STDOUT, \@cols );
   }

Answer (score 21):

Based on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1603:

```
$ hive
hive> set hive.exec.compress.output=false;
hive> create table csv_dump ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' as
hive> select ...YOUR_SELECT_QUERY_HERE...;
$ hadoop dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/csv_dump/* > ~/csv_dump.csv
```

Comment: The last command is deprecated now. Equivalent new command is almost the same - "hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/csv_dump/* > ~/csv_dump.csv". The key takeaway is that hadoop map hive tables to fs namespace /user/hive/warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and this is how I was able to address it.

Step 1 - Loaded the data from hive table into another table as follows

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestHiveTableCSV;
>   CREATE TABLE TestHiveTableCSV ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' AS
>   SELECT Column List FROM TestHiveTable;

Step 2 - Copied the blob from hive warehouse to the new location with appropriate extension

> Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy 
>   `-DestContext $destContext`
>   -SrcContainer "Source Container" 
>   `-SrcBlob "hive/warehouse/TestHiveTableCSV/000000_0"`
>   -DestContainer "Destination Container" `
>   -DestBlob "CSV/TestHiveTable.csv"

Hope this helps!

Best Regards,
Dattatrey Sindol (Datta)
http://dattatreysindol.com

Answer (score 0):

You can specify and customize how to store your tables by Hive SerDe mechanism.
Thanks to **ogrodnek** user on GitHub, there is [CSV SerDe](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) implementation.

It's a kind of obsolete (hive 0.5) but can be easily adopted to new hive version.
All I had to do for success with it - just changing build config to my hive distribution and version (I used pom.xml for maven in **kunkunur**'s pull request) and adding this lines into **CSVSerde.java** to satisfy new API:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeStats;
....
....
@Override
public SerDeStats getSerDeStats() {
// no support for statistics
return null;
}
```

Then you can just run `hadoop dfs -get /table/or/partition/location /local/destination` (or even use a -cat with pipes or single file output) to load data from hadoop - it will be already in CSV format.